# Jekyll blog published on github pages with project url

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have created a default jekyll blog and published it to this [repo](https://github.com/deivyd321/deivydas.github.io).

The problem is that my blog is hosted on https://deivyd321.github.io/deivydas.github.io/

but not on `https://deivyd321.github.io`

How can I fix this?

Comment: After freshly reading github pages docs I see that this is impossible. Closing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the url and baseurl in the `_config.yml` file like so:

```
url: 'https://deivyd321.github.io'
baseurl: ''
```